# Laravel registration page eero

Tags: php, laravel, controller, registration

Please I have a laravel website which have been working fine then all of a sudden when a user uses a referral link to register, the page will reload and redirect back to the registration page. I tried it for few times and it works then I used the new referral link to register another new account and didn't work again ever since then. And its not showing any error message but rather bounce back to same page. I have checked the RegistrationController and all the code is still fine as same before. Please I really need this help.

Thanks in Advance

Below is my RegistrationControl

`public function getRegistrationPage(){
return view('auth.register');
}

```
public function storeUser(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
 
    'name' => 'required|max:30',
    'email' => 'required|unique:users', 
    'phone' => 'required|min:10|unique:users',
    'username' => 'required|min:5|unique:users|regex:/^\S*$/u',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    'country' => 'required',
    'state' => 'required',   
]);
    
    $email_code = strtoupper(Str::random(6));
    $email_time = Carbon::parse()->addMinutes(5);
    $phone_code = strtoupper(Str::random(6));
    $phone_time = Carbon::parse()->addMinutes(5);
    $upliner = Cookie::get('referral');
    $uplinerUsername = Cookie::get('referral');
  
    $email_verify = 1;
    $phone_verify = 1;
    $user    =  new User();
    
    
    
 
    
        if($upliner == null){
        $upliner = 0;
    }
    else{
        $chkUserRef = User::where('reference', $upliner)->first();
       
        
        if($chkUserRef == null){
            return redirect('register');
            
            
        }else{
            $user_id =  $chkUserRef->id;
            $upliner = $user_id;
        }
    }
    
  
    
        $data['name'] = $user->name = $request['name'];
        
        
        $data['email'] =$user->email = $request['email'];
        $user->phone = $request['phone'];
        $data['username'] = $user->username =  $request['username'];
        $user->reference = $request['username'];
        $user->country = $request['country'];
        $user->state = $request['state'];
        $user->under_reference = $upliner;
        $user->email_verify = $email_verify;
        $user->email_code = $email_code;
        $user->email_time = $email_time;
        $user->phone_verify = $phone_verify;
        $user->phone_code = $phone_code;
        $user->phone_time = $phone_time;
        $data['password'] = $user->password = bcrypt($request['password']);
    $saved = $user->save();
    
    


    
    if($saved){
            //send  mail to the registered user
    Mail::send('emails.welcome-email', ['data' => $data], function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from('noreply@example.com', 'example.com')
            ->to($data['email'], $data['username'], $data['name'])

            ->subject('Welcome Email');
    });
    
    
    //send mail to Admin
    $data['adminEmail'] = "example@gmail.com";
    
    
    
    Mail::send('emails.registration-notification', ['data' => $data], function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from('noreply@example.com', 'example.com')
            ->to($data['adminEmail'], $data['username'], $data['email'], $data['name'])

            ->subject('User Registeration Notification');
    });
    
    
    
    //send mail to referrer
    if($uplinerUsername != null){
      
      
      $chkReff = User::where('username',$uplinerUsername)->first();
     
      if($chkReff == null){
      
      
      return redirect('register');
      
      }
      else{
      
      
        //get the person's details and send mail
       $userReff = User::where('username',$uplinerUsername)->first();
        
       
        
        $data['userEmail'] = $userReff->email;
        $data['refUsername'] = $userReff->username;
        
     
        
        Mail::send('emails.referral-notification', ['data' => $data], function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from('noreply@example.com', 'example.com')
            ->to($data['userEmail'], $data['username'], 
            $data['refUsername'], $data['userEmail'], $data['email'], $data['name'])

            ->subject('Referral Notification');
    });
      }
    }
    return redirect('login');
        
    }
 `
```

Comment: please show me the error

Comment: are these users by any chance using chrome?

Comment: Yes please they are. I am too

Comment: @hammed it doesn't show any error after redirecting back to the registration page

Comment: How about we check the `RegistrationController`? (post the relevant part only please) - have you checked the error-logs?

Comment: So I decided to use another browser just as instead of chrome just as @lagbox7 asked and it registered but the issue am still facing now is that no matter the referral link I used to register, it will still have same one ID on the database. What I mean is if a register with localhost/ma/register?ref=A then try again using another user's referral link, it will still have the ID of that A instead of showing that B referred the user. I really need this help please

Comment: The user table in the database is under_reference which is where the referral ID is shown and yet if i use chrome browser, the form will not register